# Query has different result when run directly compared to when used as a subquery

Tags: mariadb

I have a query that I will just call $QUERY to describe the problem that I'm seeing.

If I run $QUERY in the database, I get 287 rows. One of the columns is patientuid. If I count up how many rows have patientuid=40634, I see 3 rows.

Separately, I run "select * from ($QUERY) x where patientuid=40634" and I get 7 rows.

That tells me that $QUERY is actually giving me 7 rows where patientuid=40634, but when I run $QUERY, it is only showing me 3 of them. If I subselect the patientuid that I want, it shows me all rows. Hopefully this problem is obvious. The query gives me 3 rows for that patientuid value, but when I use it as a subquery, I get 7 rows. How is it possible for a query to display 3 rows on the screen, but when used as a subquery, it produces 7 rows?

I am using MariaDB RDS on AWS (10.3.23-MariaDB-log). I'm typing the query directly into the console, using the CLI mysql client from an AWS cloud server. My goal is to remove anything that could be causing this problem.

I thought that the database might be flaky, but it isn't. I get very consistent results. It simply filters results when I run $QUERY. But, when I make $QUERY a subselect and get specific patientuid values from it, I get all the results.

The query, which I doubt will be helpful for this problem, is:

```
select fu.patientuid patientuid, int_date, ini_sbp, fu_date, fu_sbp
from (
  select patientuid, bpdate fu_date, min(sbp) fu_sbp
  from bps
  where bpdate between '2020-03-31' and '2021-03-31'
  and sbp>0
  group by patientuid, bpdate
) fu
join (
  select patientuid, ini_date, floor(bp/1000) ini_sbp, int_date, int_cat
  from (
    select intdb.patientuid patientuid, intdb.ini_date ini_date, min(1000*bps.sbp+bps.dbp) bp, intdb.int_date, intdb.int_cat
    from (
      select intd.patientuid patientuid, max(bpdate) ini_date, int_date, int_cat
      from (
        select mcd.patientuid patientuid, mcd.startdate int_date, mcd.cat int_cat
        from (
          select m.patientuid patientuid, min(m.startdate) startdate, mc.cat cat
          from medications m
          join pub.medcats mc
          on m.generic=mc.generic
          and m.startdate between '2018-03-31' and '2021-03-31'
          join pub.cats c
          on mc.cat=c.id
          and c.parent in ('ah','ccb','d')
          and c.id not in ('ccb','d')
          group by m.patientuid, mc.cat
        ) mcd
        join (
          select m.patientuid patientuid, startdate, mc.cat cat
          from medications m
          join pub.medcats mc
          on m.generic=mc.generic
          and m.startdate between '2018-03-31' and '2021-03-31'
          join pub.cats c
          on mc.cat=c.id
          and c.parent in ('ah','ccb','d')
          and c.id not in ('ccb','d')
          join pub.maxdoses md
          on m.generic=md.generic
          and m.dailydose>=md.stdose
          group by m.patientuid, mc.cat
        ) msd
        on mcd.patientuid=msd.patientuid
        and mcd.cat=msd.cat
        and mcd.startdate=msd.startdate
      ) intd
      join (
        select patientuid, bpdate
        from bps
        where bpdate between '2018-03-31' and '2021-03-31'
        group by patientuid, bpdate
      ) bpd
      on intd.patientuid=bpd.patientuid
      and bpd.bpdate<=intd.int_date
      group by intd.patientuid, intd.int_date, intd.int_cat
    ) intdb
    join bps
    on intdb.patientuid=bps.patientuid
    and intdb.ini_date=bps.bpdate
    group by intdb.patientuid, intdb.ini_date, intdb.int_date, intdb.int_cat
  ) intdbp
  where bp>=140000
  or (bp%1000)>=90
) iniint
on fu.patientuid=iniint.patientuid
and datediff(fu.fu_date,iniint.int_date) between 7 and 180
where fu.patientuid between 40583 and 42920
```

Comment: Your `msd` subquery has `select ... startdate,` and `group by m.patientuid, mc.cat` so it can give inconsistent results.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thank you. That appears to be the source of the problem. I changed it to min(startdate) and I'm getting 7 rows in both the query itself and the check as a subquery.